# calculate distance between 2 points using Javascript API in IONIC 2

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to get the current position of the user and calculate the distance between this position and others positions. I am using this tutorial : [Create a Nearby Places List with Google Maps in Ionic 2](https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-nearby-places-list-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2-part-2/).
This is the code:

```
let usersLocation;
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

   usersLocation = { lat :position.coords.latitude ,  lng : position.coords.longitude }
   locations.map((location) => {

    let placeLocation = {
      lat: location.latitude,
      lng: location.longitude
    };

    location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
        usersLocation,
        placeLocation,
        'miles'
    ).toFixed(2);
  });

});
```

The problem is : The usersLocation variable is not set with the latitude and the longitude of the current user's postion. Can you help me!!

Comment: Your .then function is only used when successful outcome of calling getCurrentPosition.  You should have a good way to catch errors, using error function: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises.  The error function will help you determine what failure may be happening when calling getCurrentPosition().  I bet your getting an error from calling getCurrentPosition() and are eating it.

Comment: I used the method indicated in the link above , but it does not enter in the 2 cases success or error. I am calling the function getCurrentPosition() in another provider and it work fine.

Comment: Does your config.xml have feature allowing permissions for gps

Comment: No. It does not have that feature.

Comment: Make sure you've followed https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html to enable using gps.

Comment: I change the browser from Firefox to Chrome and it works.

Answer (score 13):

```
calculateDistance(lat1:number,lat2:number,long1:number,long2:number){
    let p = 0.017453292519943295;    // Math.PI / 180
    let c = Math.cos;
    let a = 0.5 - c((lat1-lat2) * p) / 2 + c(lat2 * p) *c((lat1) * p) * (1 - c(((long1- long2) * p))) / 2;
    let dis = (12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
    return dis;
  }
```

Comment: Yes. Multiply by 0.621371 to convert into miles.

Comment: So, if I divide "dis" by 1000, I get value in meters, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try google DirectionsService:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Scroll to the end of the page, the last example calculates the distance between the points.